# Method signature clashes when class and its parameters extends from the same trait

Tags: scala, generics, hierarchy, implicit

Apologies for the slightly vague title, it was difficult to try to summarize my problem into a single-liner. Hoping that the following snippets of codes explains better my intentions.

Let's start by introducing a trait for all things that are `Reduceable`:

```scala
trait Reduceable[A] {
  def reduceWith(other: A): A
}
```

Examples of such `Reduceable` things can be counters as such:

```scala
case class GenderCounter(male: Int, female: Int)
    extends Reduceable[GenderCounter] {
  override def reduceWith(other: GenderCounter): GenderCounter =
    GenderCounter(male + other.male, female + other.female)
}

case class FruitCounter(apples: Int, oranges: Int)
    extends Reduceable[FruitCounter] {
  override def reduceWith(other: FruitCounter): FruitCounter =
    FruitCounter(apples + other.apples, oranges + other.oranges)
}

GenderCounter(5, 10) reduceWith GenderCounter(4, 11)
// res: GenderCounter = GenderCounter(9,21)
```

A class with the above counters as parameters can also be itself a `Reduceable`

```scala
case class CompoundCounter(c1: GenderCounter, c2: FruitCounter)
    extends Reduceable[CompoundCounter] {
  override def reduceWith(
    other: CompoundCounter)
    : CompoundCounter = CompoundCounter(
    c1 reduceWith other.c1,
    c2 reduceWith other.c2
  )
}

CompoundCounter(GenderCounter(5, 10), FruitCounter(11, 2)) reduceWith CompoundCounter(GenderCounter(5, 10), FruitCounter(11, 2))
// res: CompoundCounter = CompoundCounter(GenderCounter(10,20),FruitCounter(22,4))
```

However, a problem arises when I try to introduce a generic `Reduceable` class **where its parameters are also generic `Reduceable`s**

```scala
case class CollectionReduceable[A, B](r1: Reduceable[A], r2: Reduceable[B])
    extends Reduceable[CollectionReduceable[A, B]] {
  override def reduceWith(
    other: CollectionReduceable[A, B])
    : CollectionReduceable[A, B] = CollectionReduceable(
    r1 reduceWith other.r1, 
    r2 reduceWith other.r2
  )
}

// error: type mismatch
// found   : other.r1.type (with underlying type Reduceable[A])
// required: A
//           r1 reduceWith other.r1,

// Desired outcome: same as CompoundCounter
```

I get the origin of the error message - its because the `reduceWith` signature of the trait calls for `other: A`, but if I change it then `GenderCounter` and `FruitCounter` will break. What can change I to achieve my intended outcome? Thanks!!

Comment: Is it possible to phrase the question and title better for it to be more easily found by future user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
case class CollectionReduceable[A <: Reduceable[A], B <: Reduceable[B]](r1: A, r2: B) extends Reduceable[CollectionReduceable[A, B]] {
  override def reduceWith(other: CollectionReduceable[A, B]): CollectionReduceable[A, B] =
    CollectionReduceable(
      r1.reduceWith(other.r1),
      r2.reduceWith(other.r2)
    )
  }

CollectionReduceable(GenderCounter(5, 10), FruitCounter(11, 2)) reduceWith CollectionReduceable(GenderCounter(5, 10), FruitCounter(11, 2))
// CollectionReduceable(GenderCounter(10,20),FruitCounter(22,4))
```

Comment: can you please add some explanation to your answer ? What was the problem and how your answer solve this?